# other explanations of as early as?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, as

Would you please rephrase this so I can better understand it?

> The money could be paid as early as next week.

What other meanings might "as early as" take on in different situations or circumstances?

Does "early" in these examples mean the same as it does in the previous example?

> Early booking is essential. as space is limited.
>
> I wake up as early as 6 o'clock
>
> I wake up at 6 o'clock

Comment: where are the bold parts ;)

Comment: "The money could be paid **as early as** next week" could be rewritten as "The money could be paid **as soon as** next week".

Answer (score 1):

"As early as" is not, as your tagging originally suggested, an idiom.

"Early" essentially denotes the beginning of a section of time. That's not a particularly technical way of reading it, but it will work for our purposes.

Following that, "as early as" indicates the beginning of a time opening. Your first given example could be rephrased thusly.

> The money could be paid any time at the beginning of next week or later.

In your later example, "I wake up as early as 6 o'clock," you could rephrase that as something along the lines of this.

> The earliest I wake up is 6 o'clock.

As you might notice, however, both are open-ended. Following the first example, I could pay at the beginning of next week, or I could wait three months. There's no ending to what it says, the boundary specifies only a minimum. The same is true in the latter example: I could wake up at six days of the week and 6:00 am one, and still say "I wake up as early as 6:00 am."

Your middle example isn't an "as early as," but "early" still keeps the same meaning. "Early booking is essential" simply means that booking near the beginning of your ability to do so is necessary. If the service begins offering tickets at noon, you'd better book as soon as possible after that starts, or else you might not be able to.

This is similar in open-endedness to the previous examples, insofar as it is also open-ended. This says "book early," but doesn't outright state any ending parameter for when tickets will no longer be available.

---

**Edit:**

It occurs to me that I failed to recognize the nuance of usage here. In certain cases, a speaker is unlikely to express "as early as" to actually mean an open-ended remark. A statement like this is meant generally as more of an empty promise. It's similar to "up to" in that sense. So at that point, you have to look to context, and the motives of the speaker.

Some advertisements on television might say you'll receive your shipment "as early as the following week." But that could mean only if you pay for express shipping, and that regular shipping would be several weeks. On the other hand, if someone is making a promise they can't realistically back out of (as, Maciej [kindly pointed out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/other-explanations-of-as-early-as#comment67824_36598)), "as early as" will probably refer to an estimated completion time, because the estimation being inaccurate wouldn't be good for the person who originally said it. "As early as Monday" would probably mean "Monday or Tuesday" in this case.

As with many other aspects of language, unfortunately, it depends a fair bit on context, and what you think the person stating it is trying to convey. I stand by the technical aspects of what I said in the beginning, that it's deliberately open-ended. But that said, Maciej was right to call me out, because I didn't include its practical usage.

In essence, one can take an "as early as" statement as a suggestion of a point in time, and the validity of that suggestion should be assessed on a case-by-case basis, with emphasis placed on the consequences of the suggestion being inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks. But, would you take two examples about in which situation would you rather use these? or when/where would you rather differentiate between these?: I wake up as early as 6 o'clock

I wake up at 6 o'clock

Comment: I'm sorry, but the answer is wrong (and particularly misleading at that). If you promise your boss to get something sorted out "as early as Monday", you can't have it done by Friday, if you want to keep your promise. "As early as" is an idiom, and it basically means "on/at", while emphasizing that it's earlier than expected. For example, if "Mozart started writing music as early as in 1762", it means he started writing it very early in his life, not that it might have been later.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski ah yes, my apologies. I meant to introduce those nuances, but forgot. Very unprofessional of me. I hope my edit finds you well.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski, if you want to promise it to your boss you should promise it "no later than Monday" and not "as early as Monday". If your boss takes a commitment to deliver something "as early as Monday" as a binding promise to deliver it on Monday, that's something about your work culture, and not about the English language.

Comment: So, is there any other phrase instead of as early as? or could assert it by "before"

Comment: @ThePhoton if you're so eager to say "I can have it done as early as on Monday", then it says something about your planning skills if you screw it up :) I guess you wouldn't really say it that way, unless you want to score points with your boss. Anyway, [the corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w10=as&w11=early&w12=as&r=) seems to agree that "as early as" can be used subjunctively, but it requires at least some context ("might have happened as early as on Friday" means "on Friday or later", as opposed to "might have happened on Friday" => "or at any other time").

Comment: If my boss says "Can you get it done next week?" and I say, "I can get it done as early as Monday", that might be a commitment to finish on Monday. If she says "When will it be done?" and I say "It might be as early as Monday," then I'm not committing...I'm saying there's some uncertainty (maybe an unforseen difficult arises or I'm assigned new urgent tasks) and it might be Monday or later.